# serverless route works twice and then crashes - address already in use :::3000

Tags: node.js, express, serverless-framework

I can't figure out why a serverless route works twice then I get
`address already in use :::3000`
and it crashes. It returns the response body back into postman the 2nd time and then crashes.

let me know if any other info is needed. I appreciate any help!

Error

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1330:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
    at Function.listen (/Users/phil/Documents/code/Phil App/app/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object../src/app.ts (/Users/phil/Documents/code/Phil App/app/backend/dist/service/src/handler.js:116:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/phil/Documents/code/Phil App/app/backend/dist/service/src/handler.js:21:30)
    at Object../src/handler.ts (/Users/phil/Documents/code/Phil App/app/backend/dist/service/src/handler.js:137:31)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/phil/Documents/code/Phil App/app/backend/dist/service/src/handler.js:21:30)
    at /Users/phil/Documents/code/Phil App/app/backend/dist/service/src/handler.js:85:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/phil/Documents/code/Phil App/app/backend/dist/service/src/handler.js:88:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at /Users/phil/Documents/code/Phil App/app/backend/node_modules/serverless-offline/dist/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/InProcessRunner.js:157:133
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async InProcessRunner.run (/Users/phil/Documents/code/Phil App/app/backend/node_modules/serverless-offline/dist/lambda/handler-runner/in-process-runner/InProcessRunner.js:157:9)
```

Very basic route

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.use(bodyParser.json({ strict: false }));

router.post('/test', async (req, res: Response) => {
    console.log('request', req.body);
    return res.status(200).json({ test: 'success' });
});

export default router;
```

app.ts

```
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import routers from './routes';
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ maxAge: 43200 }));
app.use(
    express.json({
        verify: (req: any, res: express.Response, buf: Buffer) => {
            req.rawBody = buf;
        }
    })
);

app.use('/testRoute', routers.testRouter);

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

export default app;
```

handler

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import awsServerlessExpress from 'aws-serverless-express';
import app from './app';

const logger = require('./utils/logger');
const log = logger.getLogger();
log.setName('handler');

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app);

export function service(event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context) {
    return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
}
```

Comment: You are using serverless computing but you setup the server anyway. Consider removing the `.listen...` part

Comment: Oh yea that was it. I thought I still had to listen to port. if you wanna post an answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

`awsServerlessExpress.proxy` can create multiple instances of the server

You've used `listen` method on the server

Two instances try to setup at the same port which causes the error

### Solution

Remove `listen` method, it's unnecessary, aws handles listening for you